# LightOpenId does not redirect to sign in page

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

can someone please help me get this working.

The problem is that it just attaches a querystring to the url and that's it. No google sign in page!

```
http://domain.nl/controller/function?action=verify&openid_identifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid
```

Mayby it is something specific like the fact that I use an mvc design and a htaccess file.

The solution is not clear to me right now.

Please point me in the right direction

Thanks, Richard

**In the controller....** This is the function the form points to

```
public function openid(){

        try {
    $openid = new LightOpenID;
    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
            $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
              //$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=YourDomain.in'; //this can be changed as you know...  
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
/*<form action="?login" method="post">
    <button>Login with Google</button>
</form>*/

    } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'Gebruiker heeft authenticatie geannuleerd!';
    } else {
        echo 'Gebruiker ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' heeft ' : 'heeft niet ') . 'ingelogd.';
    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the redirect doesn't work. Check if `$openid->authUrl()` returns the correct value. If it does, it's the problem has nothing to do with LightOpenID.

Also, if you plan to use site-xrds with google authentication, be sure to include the following header in the document returned by `http://your.domain/openid`:

```
header('X-XRDS-Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=your.domain');
```

Otherwise, the verification will fail.